# Some characters count twice

Tags: string, counter, pascal

Right now I'm trying to find the longest sentence in text and print out number of characters including spaces and things like that. The problem is when I encounter characters like 'š' or 'á' it counts them twice. I tried to subtract one in those cases, but that doesn't seem to work either, because it subtracts them twice too. Any idea how I could fix that? Here is the code for the counter.

```
for i:=1 to length(text) do
      case text[i] of 
        '.','!','?': begin
                        if len>p2 then p2:=len;
                        len:=0
                     end;
         else inc(len);
       end;
```

p2 is a counter for longest sentence and len is current sentence.

Comment: Can you include sample text you're having difficulty with?

Comment: How is the input text represented? If it's UTF-8, then `'á'` is encoded as two bytes.

Comment: For example 'Ahoj, jak se máš?' should be 16 characters but it returns 18.

Comment: How is the input text represented?  Is it UTF-8?

Comment: What Pascal implementation are you using?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it subtracts them twice too"? That doesn't make sense. The code you show doesn't show any of this. It doesn't even show how `len` and `p2` are initialized or what types they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me with ANSI characters, including those with diacritics. As you've not mentioned any specific character set, and your question is simply tagged as [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal), it should work for you as well. If you're dealing with other character sets, then you need to indicate which specific Pascal compiler you're using, as support for multi-byte characters differs between various Pascal dialects.

```
function LongestSentenceCharCount(const Text: string): Integer;
var
  Len: Integer;
  LongLen: Integer;
  i, CurrLen: Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(Text);
  CurrLen := 0;
  LongLen := 0;
  for I := 1 to Len do
  begin
    if Text[i] in ['.', '!', '?'] then
    begin
      if CurrLen > LongLen then
        LongLen := CurrLen;
      CurrLen := 0;
    end
    else
      Inc(CurrLen);

  end;
  Result := LongLen;
end;
```

To deal with multi-byte character sets such as UTF-8 and Unicode -

Based on some code donated to Cary Jensen for his white paper (PDF) [Delphi Unicode Migration for Mere Mortals: Stories and Advice from the Front Lines](http://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf) by Seppy Bloom (at the time Team Leader for RTL/VCL at Embarcadero), you can use some of the normalization functionality available in Windows since Vista and later. I've adapted my function above to use that code from Seppy (included below), along with a sample app to demonstrate using it. The code was developed, compiled and tested in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, so if you're using a different compiler you'll have to adjust it, and clearly it won't work if you're not running under Windows Vista or higher.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, WinAPI.Windows;

const
  NormalizationOther = 0;
  NormalizationC     = 1;
  NormalizationD     = 2;
  NormalizationKC    = 5;
  NormalizationKD    = 6;

function IsNormalizedString(NormForm: Integer; lpString: LPCWSTR;
  cwLength: Integer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Normaliz.dll';

function NormalizeString(NormForm: Integer; lpSrcString: LPCWSTR;
  cwSrcLength: Integer; lpDstString: LPWSTR;
  cwDstLength: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'Normaliz.dll';

function NormalizedStringLength(const Str: string): Integer;
var
  Buf: string;
begin
  if not IsNormalizedString(NormalizationC, PChar(Str), -1) then
  begin
    SetLength(Buf, NormalizeString(NormalizationC, PChar(Str),
                                   Length(Str), nil, 0));
    Result := NormalizeString(NormalizationC, PChar(Str),
                                   Length(Str), PChar(Buf), Length(Buf));
  end
  else
    Result := Length(Str);
end;

function LongestSentenceLen(const Text: string): Integer;
var
  Len: Integer;
  i, CurrLen: Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(Text);
  CurrLen := 0;
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Len do
  begin
    // Replaces 'if Text[i] in ['.', '!', '?']', which will work
    // but generates a compiler warning.
    if CharInSet(Text[i], ['.', '!', '?']) then 
    begin
      if CurrLen > Result then
        Result := CurrLen;
      CurrLen := 0;
    end
    else
      Inc(CurrLen, NormalizedStringLength(Text[i]));
  end;
end;

var
  Test: string;

begin
  Test := 'Ahoj, jak se máš? Hello World.';
  WriteLn(Test);
  WriteLn(Format('Longest: %d', [LongestSentenceLen(Test)]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The output of the above is

```
Ahoj, jak se más? Hello World.
Longest: 16
```

Comment: "... *with any ASCII characters including those with diacritics* ..." -- No ASCII characters have diacritics. The ASCII character set includes only 128 characters; Accented characters are represented in some non-ASCII format such as Latin-1, UTF-8, or UTF-16.

Comment: I'm usually using online compiler at tutorialspoint but it does the same thing in freepascal I think, haven't tried lately.

Comment: No, [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit character set (the link is to the Wikipedia article). There are a plethora of "extended" character sets *based* on ASCII, but "extended ASCII" is not ASCII.

Comment: @Keith: Rephrased. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem the OP was asking about. Both the code in the question and the code in your answer treat `Text` as an array of characters (presumably 1 byte each). If `Text` contains UTF-8 encoded text, then both versions will count `'á''` as two characters.

Comment: @Keith: No, it works with UTF-16 Unicode in Delphi 10.1 Berlin and 10 Seattle. The poster has not mentioned UTF-8 in any way. It appears it was only an online compiler that was an issue.

Comment: Yes, it should work with an implementation that has 16-bit `char` and uses a UTF-16 encoding (at least for characters within the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)). But the code in the question should *also* work with such an implementation. You've expanded the code in the question, but not in a way that addresses the problem the OP is asking about (non-ASCII characters being miscounted).

Comment: @Keith: Once again, I asked the poster about character sets, and the poster responded that it works with other than a specific online compiler, so apparently it solves the poster's problem. There is still no mention, in either the question, the comments, or the poster's (non) answer to the question that indicates that UTF-8 is involved.

Comment: UTF-8 input is the only explanation I can think of for the symptom the OP asked about (accented letters being counted as 2 characters, while  unaccented characters are counted as 1 character). I don't think the OP understands the situation. Again, I don't believe that your answer actually solves the OP's problem. (I could be mistaken.)

Comment: I also thought of UTF-8. That is the only explanation that makes sense, IMO.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Edited to include support for MCBS, including UTF-8.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Edited to include support for MCBS, including UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how the input text is represented, but the symptoms you're seeing are consistent with UTF-8 input.

ASCII is a 7-bit character set that does not include any accented letters. Your variable `text` is presumably an array of characters. For a string like `Ahoj, jak se mas?`, each character occupies one slot in the array. For a string like `Ahoj, jak se máš?`, the `'á'` and `'š'` characters are outside the ASCII range, and each is represented as 2 bytes and therefore 2 slots in the array.

The [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) explains how the UTF-8 encoding works.

I suggest temporarily adding something like:

```
writeln('text[', i, '] = ''', text[i], ''' = ', ord(s[i]));
```

after the `begin` of your `for` loop so you can see the value of each character.

That explains the problem you're seeing, but not how to solve it. That depends on what kind of support your Pascal implementation has for non-ASCII text. As far as I know, the Pascal language itself has no such support, but some particular implementations mmight.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I was only working on this inside the online compiler I mentioned. Everywhere else I tried (free pascal and turbo pascal) it works just fine.

Thank you for help, I didn't think different compilers would make a difference.

Comment: The difference is the encoding. Like Keith, I think that your text is UTF-8, which stores most non-ASCII characters as sequences of 2 to 4 bytes, but ASCII as single bytes. Compilers like old Turbo Pascal or a compiler like FreePascal do not necessarily do that, at least not by default.